# API Key is not associated with method when importing an OpenAPI spec into API Gateway using AWS Cloudformation

Tags: swagger, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, api-key

**SWAGGER SPEC**

```
{
   "swagger": "2.0",
   "info": {
      "title": "Player API without header.",
      "description": "A simple API for Player resources",
      "version": "1.0.2",
      "contact": {
         "name": "Kevin Sookocheff",
         "url": "https://sookocheff.com",
         "email": "kevin@sookocheff.com"
      }
   },
   "securityDefinitions": {
      "apiKey": {
         "type": "apiKey",
         "name": "x-api-key",
         "in": "header"
      }
   },
   "x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source": "HEADER",
   "paths": {
      "/player/{id}": {
         "get": {
            "security": [
               {
                  "apiKey": []
               }
            ],
            "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
               "credentials": {
                  "GetAtt": "APIGatewayIntegrationRole.Arn"
               },
               "type": "aws_proxy",
               "httpMethod": "POST",
               "uri": {
                  "Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:testFunc/invocations"
               }
            },
            "description": "Returns a Player resource",
            "produces": [
               "application/json"
            ],
            "responses": {
               "200": {
                  "description": "A player resource.",
                  "schema": {
                     "$ref": "#/definitions/Player"
                  }
               }
            },
            "parameters": [
               {
                  "name": "x-api-key",
                  "in": "header",
                  "description": "API Key",
                  "required": true,
                  "type": "string"
               },
               {
                  "name": "id",
                  "in": "path",
                  "description": "Identifier of player to retreive",
                  "required": true,
                  "type": "string"
               }
            ]
         },
         "put": {
            "security": [
               {
                  "apiKey": []
               }
            ],
            "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
               "credentials": {
                  "GetAtt": "APIGatewayIntegrationRole.Arn"
               },
               "type": "aws_proxy",
               "httpMethod": "POST",
               "uri": {
                  "Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:test-events-lambda/invocations"
               }
            },
            "description": "Updates a Player resource",
            "consumes": [
               "application/json"
            ],
            "produces": [
               "application/json"
            ],
            "parameters": [
               {
                  "name": "x-api-key",
                  "in": "header",
                  "description": "API Key",
                  "required": true,
                  "type": "string"
               },
               {
                  "name": "requestPayload",
                  "in": "body",
                  "schema": {
                     "$ref": "#/definitions/Player"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "name": "id",
                  "in": "path",
                  "type": "string",
                  "required": true
               }
            ],
            "responses": {
               "200": {
                  "description": "Updated player resource.",
                  "schema": {
                     "$ref": "#/definitions/Player"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "/store": {
         "get": {
            "summary": "Buy some cool avatars, unlock gold and other stuff",
            "security": [
               {
                  "apiKey": []
               }
            ],
            "parameters": [
               {
                  "name": "x-api-key",
                  "in": "header",
                  "description": "API Key",
                  "required": true,
                  "type": "string"
               }
            ],
            "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
               "credentials": {
                  "GetAtt": "APIGatewayIntegrationRole.Arn"
               },
               "type": "aws_proxy",
               "httpMethod": "POST",
               "uri": {
                  "Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:testFunc/invocations"
               }
            },
            "responses": {
               "200": {
                  "description": "TBD",
                  "schema": {
                     "$ref": "#/definitions/Player"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "definitions": {
      "Player": {
         "type": "object",
         "properties": {
            "playerId": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "alias": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "displayName": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "profilePhotoUrl": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         },
         "required": [
            "playerId",
            "alias"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

**CLOUDFORMATION TEMPLATE**

I have added a few `api gateway swagger extensions` as needed. I am using cloudformation to create an API Gateway that has an API Key.

```
{
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
   "Resources": {
      "PlayersAPI": {
         "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
         "Properties": {
            "Name": "Player API without header",
            "Description": "A demo API for Player management",
            "Body": {
              // Swagger spec goes here.
            }
         }
      },
      "PlayersAPIDeployment": {
         "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment",
         "Properties": {
            "RestApiId": {
               "Ref": "PlayersAPI"
            }
         }
      },
      "TestStage": {
         "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Stage",
         "Properties": {
            "StageName": "test",
            "RestApiId": {
               "Ref": "PlayersAPI"
            },
            "DeploymentId": {
               "Ref": "PlayersAPIDeployment"
            }
         }
      },
      "PlayersAPIKey": {
         "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey",
         "DependsOn": [
            "PlayersAPIDeployment",
            "TestStage"
         ],
         "Properties": {
            "Name": "what-the-key",
            "Description": "Create an API Key using Cloudformation.",
            "Enabled": true,
            "StageKeys": [
               {
                  "RestApiId": {
                     "Ref": "PlayersAPI"
                  },
                  "StageName": "test"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "APIGatewayIntegrationRole": {
         "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
         "Properties": {
            "Path": "/",
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
               "Version": "2012-10-17",
               "Statement": [
                  {
                     "Sid": "",
                     "Effect": "Allow",
                     "Principal": {
                        "Service": [
                           "lambda.amazonaws.com",
                           "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
                        ]
                     },
                     "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "Policies": [
               {
                  "PolicyName": "root",
                  "PolicyDocument": {
                     "Version": "2012-10-17",
                     "Statement": [
                        {
                           "Effect": "Allow",
                           "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                           "Resource": "*"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

The cloudformation stack has been created successfully, while trying to validate that the resources were created correctly, I found that:

- API Gateway is created with all the methods and the methods have a required API Key.
- API is deployed to a stage as expected..
- API Key is created but it looks like it has **not been associated with the methods that require the API Key**

When I attempt to invoke the API with `X-API-KEY` set to the value of the API key copied from the console as-is, I get a `403` status code with the message:

```
{
  "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

I have tried re-deploying the API, deleting and creating the stack again and so on.

I want to know if the swagger spec or the cloudformation template is missing a piece of the puzzle? If not, what is the issue and how can I rectify the defect?

Comment: Can you advise on if and how you validated the swagger.json?

Comment: I converted from YAML to JSON. I fixed the missing bits and indentation now. Please feel free to validate this on https://apidevtools.org/swagger-parser/online/# or on swaggerhub.

This might be true of the CFN as well.